# Convert HTML String to PDF with native PrintedPdfDocument

Tags: android, android-pdf-api

How can I convert `HTML` string (created on the fly) to `PDF` only using native `PrintedPdfDocument` (`API` 19 or higher)? I look for the solution in which I do not need to add any external libraries.

Comment: I am not aware of any direct way to get a PDF from HTML without using libraries. While Android 4.4+ is capable of printing HTML via a `WebView`, there is no direct way for you to get the PDF that might be used as the printed content.

Comment: WebView does not solve my problem because even though I can easily generate PDF from WebView content, I can only do it after explicitely displaying it on the screen. If after adding webView.setVisibility(View.GONE); the app would work, I could use it in my case. But adding GONE causes that no content is able to be captured. I am not sure if you can understand me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the HTML is very limited, you can try `TextView` and some HTML-to-`Spanned` converter (e.g., `Html.fromHtml()`).

Or, as I noted in comments, you can use `WebView`, though you indicate that it does not meet your business requirements, and I am not sure that you can get to the PDF anyway.

Otherwise, your only library-free option is to send the HTML to a server, one that can return to you a PDF.

Comment: Please read my comment above. I need a solution in which I can generate PDF in a background (or e.g. with visibility GONE)

Comment: @Annabelle: "Please read my comment above" -- please read my answer above, specifically "though you indicate that it does not meet your business requirements, and I am not sure that you can get to the PDF anyway". At least with `TextView`, you should be able to create one that is not attached to the view hierarchy, but that you manually `measure()` and `layout()` to your desired size, then use that with `PdfDocument`. Otherwise, your choices are libraries, servers, or writing your own HTML parser and implementing your own low-level `Canvas` drawing code.